# Is there a new Safari bug with the File Browse/Upload control?

Tags: browser, safari

I support a website for my job that includes a few pages that do File Uploads. We haven't touched those pages in months. But in the last few days, we've suddenly been fielding calls from Mac users who don't get the File Browse box when they click on the button.

Anyone else seeing this problem? Has there been an update from Apple for Safari in the last few days? We've been advising they download FireFox but a few have suggested filing a bug with 'Safari'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked "Software Update" on my mac and there have not been any Safari updates in the last couple weeks. I haven't used the update in a while (I have a bunch of stuff sitting there waiting to be updated).